# Why Javascript method is not getting called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity

I am trying to check in the form if there is an existing item already exists in the db but it seems that javascript code itself is not getting called. Here is my code.

```
<div class="field-group">
    <label class="label">Product Name</label>
        <input class="text" id="discovery-product-name" type="text" name="productName"  value="$textutils.htmlEncode(${productName})" required>
        <span id="result_product"></span>
<div >
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
    AJS.$(function(){

    AJS.$("#discovery-product-name").blur(function() {


        var product_name = AJS.$("#discovery-product-name").val();
        AJS.log(product_name);


    jQuery.ajax(
        AJS.params.baseURL + "/rest/leangearsrestresource/1.0/message/project/{product_name}",

        username_check_PostAjaxOptions(product_name)).done(function (result) {
            AJS.log(result);
            if (result.success) {

                if(result=='A DS Already exists')
                {
                    $('#result_product').html('Discovery Project already exist');
                    $('.save-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#result_product').html(product_name+' is valid username');
                }

            }
        })
    });

    function username_check_PostAjaxOptions (product_name) {
        return {
            "cache": false,
            "contentType": 'application/json',
            "dataType": 'json',
            "processData": false,
            "type": 'GET'
        };
    }
});
```

In the browser debugger console it does not print anything. Ideally the blur function should work as soon as I leave the field.

Comment: is it hitting your server? are you getting a response after ajax?

Comment: you set your base url but i dont see you set that in your ajax options

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling anything in your code. You are adding `AJS.params.baseURL` to the string `"/rest/leangearsrestresource/1.0/message/project/{product_name}"`, then follow with a comma. There should be a function call there somewhere, I guess, but your code has syntax errors, it won't run in the first place. It has nothing to do with your `username_check_PostAjaxOptions` not being called, there's nothing being called.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a `$.ajax(` before `AJS.params.baseURL + ...`.
(Thanks Ruben, your comment made me realise that, now the comma makes sense too).

As your code currently stands, the last `)` before `.done` is unmatched, causing a syntax error:

```
username_check_PostAjaxOptions(product_name)).done(function (result) {
```

The console has to be telling you this, though.

Comment: Removing that 2nd `)`, the code still wouldn't work, as he is returning an Object, and `Object.prototype.done` doesn't exist.

Comment: I cannot see anything in the browser console.

Comment: @user_dev Reloading the page with the console already open might (have) help(ed). Also, what browser?

Comment: @Siguza: Reloading just clears the value from the field with nothing in console. I am using chrome.

Comment: @user_dev What happens when you paste your (old) code directly into the console on your website?

Answer (score 0):

Given the signature of the comma based statement, I can only assume you were trying to do an AJAX call but you forgot calling it, you have:

```
  AJS.params.baseURL + "/rest/leangearsrestresource/1.0/message/project/{product_name}",username_check_PostAjaxOptions(product_name))
```

Assuming jQuery is in AJS.$ then:

```
 AJS.$.ajax(AJS.params.baseURL + "/rest/leangearsrestresource/1.0/message/project/{product_name}",username_check_PostAjaxOptions(product_name))
```

Basically you forgot to put:

```
 AJS.$.ajax(
```

Comment: Open up the Network tab in chrome F12->Network and trigger the blur event by losing the focus of the input (not just by leaving the mouse out of the input, that's another event), then see if it triggers the petition.

Comment: @MinuFour: No it does not. In fact those functions are not getting triggered at all.